# Reuse Office Word web addin project code for Excel and Presentation Addin

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, word-addins

I have created the project Office Word web addin and implemented document save to store in sharepoint, same functionality is required for Excel and PowerPoint. But Office Web word addin does not have instance / variable like Excel (Excel.run) or Powerpoint (PowerPoint.run).

1. Can the project(Office Word web addin) be reused for Excel.run and PowerPoint.run?
2. If not, should we create new project for Excel and Presentation?
3. How can we reuse code from Office web word addin?

Comment: Please Could you help me!  I am working on word web addins , but facing this issue:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63410474/word-web-addin-getsliceasync-only-return-first-slice-of-data). Please suggest!